# How can i solve "Socket read timed out" exception while iterating result set?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, jdbc, ojdbc

What can be the reason of facing **java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out** while iterating over the result set with Spring's **rs.next()** method?

Edit: I use org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor.extractData(ResultSet) while looping in result set with rs.next method.

Ps: i use tomcat 6, java1.7, ojdbc14

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1043)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:297)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:213)
    at com.company.project.db.sp.mySP.extractData(mySP.java:188)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.processResultSet(JdbcTemplate.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractOutputParameters(JdbcTemplate.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1014)
```

Edit 2: Here is my code:

```
public class mySpClass extends StoredProcedure implements  ResultSetExtractor<Object>  {    
private final String SQL = "pack.mySp";
private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(mySpClass.class);
public mySpClass(DataSource ds){    
    this.setDataSource(ds);
    this.setSql(SQL);
    // declare all parameters,cursors like this.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("P_START_TIMESTAMP",   Types.TIMESTAMP));
    this.compile();
}
public mySpClassSPResult runIt(//Here inputParams) throws SQLException {

    //business code  and input 
    try {           
        spOut = execute(inputParams);
    } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {         
        logger.error("SP execution throwed an exception",dataAccessException);
        throw dataAccessException;
    }

    Map<String,myReturnObject> returnObjects=(Map<String, myReturnObject>) spOut.get("P_RC_ReturnObjects");

    return new mySpClassSPResult(returnObjects);
}

@Override
public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

        Map<String,myReturnObject> returnObjects=new HashMap<String,myReturnObject>();

        while(rs.next()){ // here is where time out exception occurs
            //business code fills returnObjects
        }
        return returnObjects;

}
```

}

Comment: Seems your Oracle DB stalls. How big is the expected resultset? Try to paginate if it is huge.

Comment: @Fildor Actually, for 9 rows of results it's ok, but for 10 rows i am facing with this exception.

Comment: OK, then it is def. not the size ...

Comment: Do you have long calcilations / operations for each row? Or just collect and handle later?

Comment: @Jan, no i don't. Just looping in the result set. And see the edit please. I have T4C connection which time outs during looping.

Comment: "for 9 ok for 10 error" - can you elaborate? Do you maybe run into a LOCK with your select and this causes your statement to wait until at some point the (possibly very large) socket timeout hits?

Comment: @Jan, but while looping in resultset, would't i already be done with select or any other db operations? I got the all data, already. Also, when i try the sp with oracle sql developer i am getting the same mistake when i try to loop data after i got the data, again

Comment: Maybe it would be best if you shared some of your code here. Like everything from preparing the statement/call until the line of error

Comment: @Jan please see edit 2